# Newly added node is not available in ceph pool

Tags: kubernetes, ceph

Absolute newbie in Ceph and down with a problem.

Added 3 new nodes to my  K8's setup and its available and in Ready state -  as per `kubectl get nodes`. But, cant see the same in my ceph pool, while listing using `ceph osd tree`.

What am i doing wrong ?

Deployed the k8 using Ansible Playbook and it generally takes care of the storage configuration.

Also, can I delete the replicapool to save some space ? what impact will it cause ?

```
--- POOLS ---
POOL                   ID  STORED   (DATA)   (OMAP)   OBJECTS  USED     (DATA)   (OMAP)  %USED   MAX AVAIL  QUOTA OBJECTS  QUOTA BYTES  DIRTY    USED COMPR  UNDER COMPR
device_health_metrics   1      0 B      0 B      0 B        0      0 B      0 B     0 B       0        0 B  N/A            N/A                0         0 B          0 B
replicapool             2  805 GiB  805 GiB  9.0 MiB  221.83k  2.2 TiB  2.2 TiB  25 MiB  100.00        0 B  N/A            N/A          221.83k         0 B          0 B
```

Comment: Maybe the OSD pods couldn't be created? Check if there are OSD processes running on the new nodes. The replicapool contains data so you should check who is using that in order to determine if it can be deleted. Don't delete it until you're absolutely sure that nobody needs it anymore.

Comment: Yes I dont see the OSD pods for the new nodes but OSD process are active on the new nodes.

`ps -ef |grep osd
root      532664  532645  0 Jun15 ?        00:00:04 /rook/tini -- /rook/rook ceph osd provision
root      532678  532664  0 Jun15 ?        00:00:20 /rook/rook ceph osd provision`

Comment: Then you need to figure out why the OSDs are not created. I'm not familiar with rook so I can't really assist here.